# Laravel how to get a Model by two parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Hi I'm new to Laravel and got stuck in a Problem.

I have a model `Contact`

```
class Contact extends Eloquent {
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'contacts';
}
```

The table have these fields:

```
user_id (int)
contact_id (int)
...
```

these two fields represent the primary key.

In the `ContactsController` I have the function `store` in wich I create or update the database:

```
public function store()
{

    switch (Input::get('type')){
        case 'make_contact_request':

            $user = User::where('email', '=', Input::get('login'));

            $request_self = new Contact;
            $request_contact = new Contact;

            $request_self->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $request_self->contact_id = $user->id;
            $request_self->status = 2;
            $request_self->message = Input::get('message');

            $request_contact->user_id = $user->id;
            $request_contact->contact_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $request_contact->status = 1;
            $request_contact->message = Input::get('message');

            $request_self->save();
            $request_contact->save();
            break;
        case 'answer_contact_request':

            $request_self = Contact::where('user_id', '=',Input::get('contact_id'))->where('contact_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            //$request_self = Contact::whereRaw('user_id = '.Input::get('contact_id').' AND contact_id = '.Auth::user()->id.' ');
            $request_contact = Contact::whereRaw('user_id = '.Auth::user()->id.' AND contact_id = '.Input::get('contact_id').' ');

            $request_self->status = 3;
            $request_contact->status = 3;

            $request_self->save();
            $request_contact->save();
            break;
    }
```

}

I tried two different ways to get the `Contact` Object for the `request_self` Object and I get the following error:

```
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `contacts` set `status` = 3, `updated_at` = 2014-08-02 16:16:56 where `id` is null)"
```

for the `request_contact` Object it throws a fatal error (don't get the description) and close the session.

At the end I am at the beginning of laravel so I hope the solution is pretty easy to find :) but I dont even really know for what to search.

**Update:**

At the end I fixed the Problem with the `update` function.

```
 case 'answer_contact_request':

            $request_self = Contact::where('user_id', '=',Input::get('contact_id'))->where('contact_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->update(array('status' => 3));
            $request_contact = Contact::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('contact_id', '=', Input::get('contact_id'))->update(array('status' => 3));

            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add

```
public function scopeComposite($query, $user_id, $contact_id)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('contact_id', '=', $contact_id);
}
```

and then you can get the contact with:

```
$request_self = Contact::composite(Input::get('contact_id'), Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

source: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

I'm not sure you can make it like this.

There is a way to make sure it works:

add a column id ( auto increment, primary ) and make the group ( contact_id, user_id ) unique and you can use query scopes and id based

Comment: Hey Alexandru, Thanks a lot, but even scope didnt give back a representation of this object. I used the update function in steade and this finally worked. greetings max